# Using two varistors in series when there is no possibilty of using single component

Tags: surge-protection, varistor, surge

I need to use Varistor to protect the circuitry from 6kV 1,2/50us impulse.
Varistor has to be between input + and - wires. The operational voltage between this two input pins can be up to 1050 V.

**I have to** use this series: https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/protection/voltage/lead-disk-varistor/data_sheet/70/db/var/siov_snf_automotive.pdf

Can I use two varistor B72214X2421K501 in series between + and - pins?

**What are the drawbacks of using two varistors in series?**
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From: [https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/varistors/littelfuse_the_abcs_of_movs_application_note.pdf](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/varistors/littelfuse_the_abcs_of_movs_application_note.pdf)  (p10-47)

Q. Can MOVs be connected in series for special voltage
applications?

A. Yes. MOVs can be connected in series to provide voltage
ratings higher than those normally available, or to provide
ratings between the standard offerings